# ^C not working in zsh on Mac OSX

Tags: terminal, zsh, key-binding

Ctrl-C stopped working for me at the terminal when using zsh (on mac osx).
I didn't notice the exact moment that it happend so I can't be sure what caused it.

I didd't update zsh in a while though. and didn't touch .zshrc (I have it at a repo http://github.com/astrails/dotzsh)

If I run bash, ^C works in it.

If I run any command, like `cat`, ^C will work to stop it too. but inside zsh it just doesn't do anything.

```
bindkey | grep \\^C
```

gives

```
"^B"-"^C" self-insert
```

- zsh 4.3.10 (i386-apple-darwin10.4.3), installed though ports (zsh-devel @4.3.10_0+doc+examples+mp_completion+pcre)
- mac os 10.6.6

Comment: just tried /bin/zsh and ^C doesn't work in it too. hmmm.

Comment: Does it work without your `.zshrc`? (Try `zsh --no-rcs`.)

Comment: hmmmmm. it does. silly me. but I didn't change it in a while and there are at least 3 other people in the company using the same set of configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that was a bug in rvm (ruby version manager) that I did update lately

Answer (score 0):

I had some funny business (mostly with CTRL-A just printing out "^A" instead of moving the cursor to home position of the command line), but I got rid of it by disabled the "vi-mode" plugin in .zshrc :)

Comment: why would I disable it if thats the mode I'm using? :)
anyway, as you can see above the problem was with RVM